# Embedding MP4 videos on my website

Tags: mp4

Is there a way to display MP4 videos in its original size.  It looks like we have to provide Width and Height and if we don't it will default to some value other than it's original size.

```
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" 
CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" WIDTH="160" HEIGHT="136" >
<PARAM NAME="src" VALUE="videofilename_mp4.mov" >
<PARAM NAME="autoplay" VALUE="true" >
<EMBED SRC="videofilename_mp4.mov" TYPE="image/x-macpaint" 
PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download" WIDTH="160" HEIGHT="136" AUTOPLAY="true"></EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly you will have to read it from the metadata. I currently use the free version of Flowplayer.

You can pass it an option "scale:fit" http://flowplayer.org/documentation/api/clip.html

This tells the flash Flowplayer to read the file metadata and scale the video to fit inside the player container with the proper aspect ratio.

I know you probably don't want a flash solution but this is an option.